# Selecting only one row when the value in a column is the same

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Good afternoon all,

I am faced with the following problem:

I have created a query to select and display several columns joined from different tables within a database.

One column holds a numerical value.
This value is the same in some cases.

What I need is to only keep one row when the value is the same for a particular group of rows which has a unique identifier (indicated by another column).

I have read around the subject such as using GROUP BY, CTE, and ROW_NUMBER, but as I am quite new I have not been able to make any of these work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**My query:
**

```
SELECT S.SessionID
    , S.UserName
    , S.MachineName
    , I.SrvName
    , A.ApplicationName
    , A.WindowUniqueID

FROM Inventory I 
    INNER JOIN Session S ON S.SrvID = I.SrvID
    LEFT JOIN Application A ON S.SessionID = A.SSessionID AND S.SessionDay = A.SessionDay

WHERE S.Date >= '2021-08-26' AND S.Date < '2021-08-30'

ORDER BY SCS.UserName ASC
```

**Sample Output:**

| SessionID | UserName | MachineName | SrvName | ApplicationName | WindowUniqueID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | User1 | PC1 | PC1 | App1 | 258258 |
| 123456 | User1 | PC1 | PC1 | App1 | 258258 |
| 987654 | User1 | PC1 | PC1 | App1 | 963963 |

**Goal:**

| SessionID | UserName | MachineName | SrvName | ApplicationName | WindowUniqueID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | User1 | PC1 | PC1 | App1 | 258258 |
| 987654 | User1 | PC1 | PC1 | App1 | 963963 |

When I use the group by option I get the error "Column 'SessionID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." If I add the column, I get the same error for the next one and the next in my list.

Also using DISTINCT in the select statement does not produce the desired result, although the query runs with no errors.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't want to delete the rows, just want my result output to not show rows with duplicate values in the specific column.

Comment: *"using DISTINCT in the select statement does not produce the desired result"* Works fine for me with your sample data: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XfCoQfT3)

Answer (score 0):

In this case a DISTINCT or GROUP BY should work. If you still have duplicate data, please post the example of that as there must be a difference between.

Distinct:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT
         S.SessionID,
         S.UserName,
         S.MachineName,
         I.SrvName,
         A.ApplicationName,
         A.WindowUniqueID
FROM     Inventory I
         INNER JOIN Session S ON S.SrvID = I.SrvID
         LEFT JOIN Application A ON S.SessionID = A.SSessionID
                                    AND S.SessionDay = A.SessionDay
WHERE    S.Date >= '2021-08-26'
         AND S.Date < '2021-08-30'
ORDER BY SCS.UserName ASC;
```

Group by:

```
SELECT
         S.SessionID,
         S.UserName,
         S.MachineName,
         I.SrvName,
         A.ApplicationName,
         A.WindowUniqueID
FROM     Inventory I
         INNER JOIN Session S ON S.SrvID = I.SrvID
         LEFT JOIN Application A ON S.SessionID = A.SSessionID
                                    AND S.SessionDay = A.SessionDay
WHERE    S.Date >= '2021-08-26'
         AND S.Date < '2021-08-30'
GROUP BY S.SessionID,
         S.UserName,
         S.MachineName,
         I.SrvName,
         A.ApplicationName,
         A.WindowUniqueID
ORDER BY SCS.UserName ASC;
```

Comment: The fact that the OP explicitly states *"using DISTINCT in the select statement does not produce the desired result"* suggests that there is something that they aren't telling us.

Comment: I totaly agree ;-) Or he did something wrong with the syntax.. btw, I've added also the Group By in your fiddle result mentioned above.

Comment: You can't change a fiddle, @Peter; if you check the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XfCoQfT3) you'll note it's the same as it was before. I'm also, however, really not a fan of using a `GROUP BY` when there is no aggregation.

Comment: Oh indeed! I'll remove my remark :)